# Postfix forward email to my gmail from a gmail failed

Tags: postfix, gmail, mail-forwarding

I am not possible to forward email from gmail account to a gmail.
I come across with below link which telling that gmail is blocked to stop  looping.

https://superuser.com/questions/332389/postfix-forwarding-e-mail-to-gmail-not-working

Is it possible to do any configuration changes in Postfix files to fix it?
Does it possible to send email from the server instead of forwarding?

Thank You

Comment: Yeah relay with sasl_auth and authenticate as your Gmail account to relay from your Gmail account

Answer (score 0):

Does your Postfix allow relaying?
check in /etc/postfix/main.cf the line
relayhost=

and also the line
mydestination=